# Make directories and symlinks from names in textfile

Tags: bash

I have a list of words in a text file, one per line.

I would like to make a symbolic link for each of for each word in the text file.

For example, lets say real directory is /stuff/testing/original

Text file is of format

```
word1
word2
word3
```

I want to have /stuff/testing/word1, /stuff/testing/word2, /stuff/testing/word3, all being a symlink to /stuff/testing/original

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a BASH command (it won't work in TCSH or KSH) :

```
for NAME in $( < cat /path/to/listfile ) ; do ln -s /stuff/testing/original "${NAME}" ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the for loop above, you could use a while loop to read the file:

```
while read NAME ; do ln -s /stuff/testing/original /stuff/testing/$NAME ; done < /stuff/testing/original
```